# How to Add a String inside of another string without erasing the rest of it

Tags: string, arduino

### I'm having bad times trying to add a string inside of another string in a especific position. Every time I use this code, the rest of the string become blank.

```
double temperature = 22.1;
unsigned char pacote[16] = "#0123456789ABCDEF";
unsigned char temp_local[3];
dtostrf(temperatura, 3, 1, temp_local);
sprintf(pacote+3,"%s", temp_local);
```

or

```
sprintf(pacote+3,temp_local);
```

got the same printf:

```
#0122.1
```

istead of:

```
#0122.16789ABCDEF
```

Why is it erasing all the rest of the string and not just replace the next 4 positions after [3] and leaving the rest alone.
I'm using arduino but I think that's generic C question.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Choose *one* programming language. Different languages, different answers.

Comment: `sprintf` terminates the string the string it writes out, so it's truncating the string at the end of what it writes out.

Comment: Arduino is not C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the string data into the designated position (instead of copying the string, which includes a terminating `'\0'`):

```
memcpy(pacote+3, temp_local, strlen(temp_local));
```

Comment: OMG you are a god! My printf is now "#0122.16789ABCDE" Thank you very much! I never heard about that function :O

Answer (score 0):

if you are using C++ then use string::substr as in

new_string = old_string.substr(0,3) + "some text" + old_string.substr(3);

In pure C you first need to ensure that the destination has enough space. sprintf returns the number of characters written. Use this to ensure that destination has sufficient space. Then concatenate the two substrings with the new string as desired.